# Como executar um código só depois de terminar outro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Preciso executar a busca das cidades só depois de terminar de carregar os estados dentro do select e capturar a `ID`. Estou pegando essa `ID` para enviar outro Ajax que vai popular as cidades deste estado dentro de um outro select.

O que está acontecendo é que antes do primeiro script ***popular*** os estados, a continuação do código acaba capturando o estado selecionado anteriormente e fazendo a busca para este estado e não para o que acaba de ser escolhido.

> **O que eu preciso é que o código espere o script popular os estados.**

Sem saber para o que serve realmente, tentei usar o ***done*** achando que ele ia disparar a continuação do script só quando o outro script terminasse de popular os estados.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        data:{
            cep: $('#cep').val(),
            formato:'json'
        },
        success: function(res){

            // Seleciona tipo de logradouro e logradouro do CEP.
            $('input[name=endereco]').val(res.tipo_logradouro+' '+res.logradouro);

            // Seleciona bairro do CEP.
            $('input[name=bairro]').val(res.bairro);

            // Seleciona o estado conforme valor recebido no json ...
            // Dispara um trigger para carregar as cidades do estado ...
            $("#estado option").each(function() {

                $(this).prop('selected', false);
                if ($(this).data("sigla") == res.uf) {

                    $(this).prop('selected', true);
                    $("#estado").trigger("change");
                }

            });

        }

    }).done(function(res){

        $(this).prop('selected', false);
        $("#cidade option").each(function() {

            console.log($(this).data("cityname"));

            if ($(this).data("cityname") == res.cidade) {

                $(this).prop('selected', true);
            }  

        });                   

    });
```

Comment: Você precisa mover o código que está dentro do bloco `done` para o bloco `success`. O bloco `success` é executado quando chegar o retorna da chamada ajax, que é onde você quer executar a outra parte do código.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a opção **async** do ajax como false, leia mais aqui:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Dessa forma o script espera todo o processo acabar pra dar continuidade ao código abaixo.

Exemplo do código com async:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php',
    type: 'get',
    async: false,
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você precisa fazer não é diretamente ligado ao resultado da chamada AJAX o ideal seria colocar em uma função a parte :

```
success: function(res){

           // Faça o que tem que fazer

            minhaFuncao();
            });

        }

// fora da função que fez a chamada

function minhaFuncao(){
  // Faça o que quiser depois que acabou
}
```

Comment: É diretamente ligado. A segunda etapa depende de informações da primeira.

Comment: então você coloca o código junto do restante no `sucess`